# How do I get a Price for Amtrak rail when using the Sabre RailShopRS

Tags: sabre

I am trying to implement AMTRAK Rail bookings using Sabre's RailShopRS.

I've been able to get a list of available journeys but now I'm struggling to figure out how I get a price for those journeys. It looks like the price should be part of the availability response but there never appears to be a price anywhere.

Is this something that should be part of the initial availability response or do I have to make a new request with details of the specific train and faretype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?
http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/rail/RailServicesDescription_v1.12.0.html#amtrak

Here are some sample request and responses:
http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/rail/RS_Sample_RQ_RS_1_12_0.zip

There should be a list of 'Offers' within the response, with a reference to a JourneyId that can be used to match the fares with its corresponding journey/train option.

Comment: thanks for the pointer fcarreno. It turns out my PriceType class had been incorrectly generated and was missing a number of properties and their backers.